# Tests running in parallel - optimal threads used?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

if a VM has 2 cores and 4 logical processors, then we should be able to run 4 parallel tests optimal which can make use of the 4 available threads.
If I have mentioned 5 tests to run parallelly in my build file, then ideally 4 runs in parallel and upon completion of a test whose thread would be free can pick the last test case to execute.

so optimal parallelism is 4 only in this case. Is my understanding right.

Comment: Its a bit more complicated than that. You have physical (and logical) cores, then your OS / VM host has a thread scheduler. Applications running under the host create threads and then the host decided what thread to run on what physical core based on several factors i.e. thread priority, demand, timing etc. Its even more complicated than what I've just written but I'm limited in the amount I can write in the comments. It should give you some more insight. What language / runtime are you using?

Comment: its java and running my tests in Azure pipelines - Azure vms